# Creating a Dictionary<string,string> to generate the most frequent continuations (without Linq)

Tags: c#, beginner, hash-map, console

`Main` is added to compare the expected result with the result of the function, the war field is `GetMostFrequentNextWords`.

- What data types can be better instead of `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>`?
- Are there any problems with the usage of this data type?
- Is my code easy to read?

In Particular, the creation of Dictionaries for new keys takes a lot of code volume.

- Are `keyValuePairInternal`, `helpDictionary` good names for variables?
- Is the use of the variable `keyTwoWords` justified?

I am searching for all my problems

#### The task:

N-gram it's N adjacent words in one sentence. for example, from the text:

> "She stood up. Then she left."

you can take the next 2-grams

- "she stood",
- "stood up",
- "then she"
- and "she left",
- but **not** the next case "up then".

and 3-grams

- "she stood up"
- and "then she left",
- but **not** the case "stood up then".

with a list of sentences (the list is consist of words, that are assembled in the list of sentences) create a vocabulary of the most frequent continuations of 2-grams and 3-grams. It's the vocabulary, in which all possible beginnings of 2-grams and 3-grams are Keys, and the Values are their most frequent continuations. If there are few continuations with equal frequency, you should store a string that is smaller (with help of `String.CompareOrdinal`).

**Example** Text: "a b c d. b c d. e b c a d." You should get the next vocabulary:

1 "a": "b"

2 "b": "c"

3 "c": "d"

4 "e": "b"

5 "a b": "c"

6 "b c": "d"

7 "e b": "c"

8 "c a": "d"

From 2-grams "a b" and "a d" that met once, there is only one pair in Dictionary  "a": "b",  because it's the smaller one. From the next two 2-grams  "c d" и "c a" There is only one most frequent pair "c": "d".  And from 3-grams "b c d" and "b c a" Next pair is in vocabulary as the most frequent one "b c": "d".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApp11
{
    public static class SentencesParserTask
    {
        public static Dictionary<string, string> GetMostFrequentNextWords(List<List<string>> text)
        {
            var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            var helpDictionary = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < text.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < text[i].Count; j++)
                {
                    if (text[i].Count - j >= 3)
                    {
                        string keyTwoWords = text[i][j] + " " + text[i][j + 1];
                        if (!helpDictionary.ContainsKey(keyTwoWords))
                            helpDictionary[keyTwoWords] = new Dictionary<string, int>();

                        if (!helpDictionary[keyTwoWords].ContainsKey(text[i][j + 2]))
                            helpDictionary[keyTwoWords][text[i][j + 2]] = 0;

                        helpDictionary[keyTwoWords][text[i][j + 2]]++;
                    }

                    if (text[i].Count - j >= 2)
                    {
                        if (!helpDictionary.ContainsKey(text[i][j]))
                            helpDictionary[text[i][j]] = new Dictionary<string, int>();

                        if (!helpDictionary[text[i][j]].ContainsKey(text[i][j + 1]))
                            helpDictionary[text[i][j]][text[i][j + 1]] = 0;

                        helpDictionary[text[i][j]][text[i][j + 1]]++;
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, Dictionary<string, int>> keyValuePair in helpDictionary)
            {
                if (!result.ContainsKey(keyValuePair.Key))
                    result[keyValuePair.Key] = "";
                int maxFrequencyCount = 0;
                string maxFrequencyString = "";
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, int> keyValuePairInternal in keyValuePair.Value)
                {
                    if ((keyValuePairInternal.Value > maxFrequencyCount) || ((keyValuePairInternal.Value == maxFrequencyCount) &&
                        (string.CompareOrdinal(maxFrequencyString, keyValuePairInternal.Key) > 0)))
                    {
                        result[keyValuePair.Key] = keyValuePairInternal.Key;
                        maxFrequencyCount = keyValuePairInternal.Value;
                        maxFrequencyString = keyValuePairInternal.Key;
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
  
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //a b c d. b c d. e b c a d.
            var list = new List<List<string>>();
            list.Add(new List<string>());
            list[0].Add("a");
            list[0].Add("b");
            list[0].Add("c");
            list[0].Add("d");
            list.Add(new List<string>());
            list[1].Add("b");
            list[1].Add("c");
            list[1].Add("d");
            list.Add(new List<string>());
            list[2].Add("e");
            list[2].Add("b");
            list[2].Add("c");
            list[2].Add("a");
            list[2].Add("d");

            Console.WriteLine("The origin text : \n" );
            foreach (var sentence in list)
            {
                foreach(var word in sentence)
                {
                    Console.Write(" " + word);
                }
                Console.Write(".");
            }

            Console.Write("\n\n ");
            Console.WriteLine("Expected output: \n1 a: b \n2 b: c \n3 c: d \n4 e: b \n5 a b: c \n6 b c: d \n7 e b: c \n8 c a: d \n\n ");

            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(GetMostFrequentNextWords(list));
            int index = 1;

            Console.WriteLine("Your output (THE ORDER ISNT IMPORTANT) :");
            foreach (var keyValuePair in dictionary)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(index++ + " " + keyValuePair.Key + ": " + keyValuePair.Value);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to split your `GetMostFrequentNextWords` into small, manageable functions?

Comment: @PeterCsala I lack such experience. Should I create methods for every `foreach` or should I somehow simplify them? If the second i cant imagine anything now with my skills

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets do some refactoring together

#### `GetMostFrequentNextWords`

- If you look at this function then you can easily distinguish two parts

  - Populate the `helpDictionary`
  - Convert the `helpDictionary` to the desired format
- So, lets extract these codes into their own methods
- With these in our hand the only responsibility of the `GetMostFrequentNextWords` method is that it needs to call the methods in the right order

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetMostFrequentNextWords(List<List<string>> text)
{
    var intermediateCollection = GetIntermediateCollection(text);
    return TransformIntermediateToFinal(intermediateCollection);
}
```

or in short

```
public static Dictionary<string, string> GetMostFrequentNextWords(List<List<string>> text)
   => TransformIntermediateToFinal(GetIntermediateCollection(text));
```

#### `GetIntermediateCollection`

- If you look at the body of the nested for loop then you can spot that both `if` branches do the same thing but on different indexes/indices
- So, the common parts could (and should) be extracted and only the unique part should be provided as input

```
private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> GetIntermediateCollection(List<List<string>> text)
{
    var intermediateCollection = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
    foreach (var sentence in text)
    {
        for (int word = 0; word < sentence.Count; word++)
        {
            if (sentence.Count - word >= 3)
                UpdateCollection(intermediateCollection, sentence[word] + " " + sentence[word + 1], sentence[word + 2]);

            if (sentence.Count - word >= 2)
                UpdateCollection(intermediateCollection, sentence[word], sentence[word + 1]);
        }
    }

    return intermediateCollection;
}
```

- I've tired to use more meaningful iterator names than `i` and `j`

#### `UpdateCollection`

- This is the common part of the two if branches
- I've used `innerKey` and `outerKey` as parameter names to indicate their intended usage

```
private static void UpdateCollection(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> twoLevelCollection, string outerKey, string innerKey)
{
    if (!twoLevelCollection.ContainsKey(outerKey))
        twoLevelCollection[outerKey] = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    if (!twoLevelCollection[outerKey].ContainsKey(innerKey))
        twoLevelCollection[outerKey][innerKey] = 0;

    twoLevelCollection[outerKey][innerKey]++;
}
```

#### `TransformIntermediateToFinal`

- Here I took advantage of [C#'s deconstruction feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/functional/deconstruct) in the `foreach` loops

```
private static Dictionary<string, string> TransformIntermediateToFinal(Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> twoLevelCollection)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var (grams, innerGrams) in twoLevelCollection)
    {
        if (!result.ContainsKey(grams))
            result[grams] = "";

        int maxFrequencyCount = 0;
        string maxFrequencyString = "";
        foreach (var (word, frequency) in innerGrams)
        {
            if (frequency > maxFrequencyCount
                || (frequency == maxFrequencyCount
                    && string.CompareOrdinal(maxFrequencyString, word) > 0))
                (result[grams], maxFrequencyString, maxFrequencyCount) = (word, word, frequency);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

- Just like you in your original code I also had problem to find good naming for the iterator variables

  - Maybe it make sense to spend some time on it to find better names than these

#### `Main`

- And last but not least the caller side

```
var input = new List<List<string>>
{
    new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c", "d"},
    new List<string>() { "b", "c", "d"},
    new List<string>() { "e", "b", "c", "a", "d"},
};

Console.WriteLine("The origin text : \n");
foreach (var sentence in input)
{
    Console.Write(string.Join(" ", sentence));
    Console.Write(".");
}

Console.Write("\n\n ");
Console.WriteLine("Expected output: \n1 a: b \n2 b: c \n3 c: d \n4 e: b \n5 a b: c \n6 b c: d \n7 e b: c \n8 c a: d \n\n ");
Console.WriteLine("Actual output (the ordering doesn't matter):");

var mostFreuqentOnes = new SentencesParser().GetMostFrequentNextWords(input);
foreach (var (idx, lhs, rhs) in mostFreuqentOnes.Select((kv, idx) => (idx, kv.Key, kv.Value)))
    Console.WriteLine(idx+1 + " " + lhs + ": " + rhs);
```

---

[Here you can find a working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M58X6c)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I appreciate your help. When you were solving my question did you think about my choice of Dictionary<string,Dictionry>> data type. Was my way to solve it good?

Comment: @Sheeba334 No, I was not thinking about your data type choice. If you wish I can update my post on Monday.

Comment: You don't have to write all code. If it's not difficult just think about my choice and others that can be better. And a short plan of how to do it with a new data type will be enough. Don't want to waste your time. I have time so I can wait. Appreciate your help

Comment: @Sheeba334 Iterating through a Dictionary is considered slow compared to iterating through a List or Array (*you do this only once*). On the other hand the `ContainsKey` has quite good performance (*you do this several times*). Since there is no built-in structure for multi-dimensional string keyed arrays in .NET that's why `Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>` seems to me a good choice for this problem.